# Microsoft bot framework: Can a bot framework send offline message to someone who is not in active conversation with the bot?

Tags: botframework

I am planning to send push notifications to the user. 
Can a bot framework send offline message to someone who is not in active conversation with the bot ?

Comment: What channel are you trying to do this with?  Also what SDK are you using node/c#?

Answer (score 3):

To send a message to a user that your bot had an interaction before you can use:

> SendToConversationAsync(…),
>
> CreateConversationAsync(…),
>
> CreateDirectConversation(…)

If your bot wants to send a proactive message, you need to keep the ServiceUrl and the user’s ChannelAccount (extracted from one of the messages from that user) and use this data to send a new activity from your bot to that user using the above API.

Comment: What if he is using  Direct Line APIs? He cannot do anything correct?